# Python3 return() multiple values

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a code that sorts out alphabets from a random string and this is the draft for it:

```
def SortLetter(nonsense):
  for words in nonsense:
    if words.isalpha():
      return words

print (SortLetter("T/h,e1?Lyin]gC[a067k186e"))
```

Result:

```
T
```

Anticipated Result:

```
The Lying Cake
```

It seems like that only the first letter is returned. How could I fix this? (I don't want to print it straight out from the code though)

Thank you!

Comment: From the moment the interpreter hits a `return` statement, it considers the function done and returns that value.

Comment: also you can't really find the words and place a space between them, so the best you can do is substritute `yield` for `return` use `"".join()` in the `print` call and get the ouput without spaces.

Comment: Alternately you could use a collector variable outside the for loop that you add to within the for loop and return that collector variable at the end

Answer (score 0):

Your close. The problem is that you are iterating over letters, not words. You needs to collect your letters into words then return it. IE:

```
def SortLetter(nonsense):
  words=""
  for letter in nonsense:
    if letter.isalpha():
      words += letter
  return words

print (SortLetter("T/h,e1?Lyin]gC[a067k186e"))
```

returns:

```
TheLyingCake
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can answer to your question in more "generic way" like this example:

```
def sort_letters(nonsense = ""):
    for word in nonsense:
        if word.isalpha():
            yield word

print("".join(sort_letters("T/h,e1?Lyin]gC[a067k186e")))
```

Output:

```
TheLyingCake
```

otherwise, if you want to have the exact output you gave you can try something like this using the same `sort_letters()` method above:

```
data = "".join(sort_letters("T/h,e1?Lyin]gC[a067k186e"))
pretty_output = data[0] + "".join([" " + k if k.istitle() else k for k in data[1:]])
# Or, like this way
# data = list(sort_letters("T/h,e1?Lyin]gC[a067k186e"))
# pretty_output = data[0] + "".join([" " + k if k.istitle() else k for k in data[1:]])
print(pretty_output)
```

Output:

```
The Lying Cake
```

Comment: Any reason not to put the `space` logic in the original generator? `if word.isupper(): yield ' '` before the `yield word`

Comment: Well there is not any logic behind. It was only the first thing that came to my mind when i posted the answer. Now, with your comment, your code is more pythonic than mine. If you don't mind, can i update my answer and put your code instead of mine ? Thanks.